# Sending data in email from different textarea

Tags: laravel, email

I have code:

```
Mail::send('emails.einkaufen', ['data'=>$request['repair_report_einkaufen']], function ($m) use ($delivery)
```

but I have to send also in email.einkaufen also data from 'repair_report_einkaufen1. How can I add second data?

Answer (score 0):

Define $data as array above your Mail::send function, and pass it in:

```
//Define an empty array first
$data = []; 
//Popuilate the array
$data['repair_report_einkaufen'] = $request['repair_report_einkaufen'];
$data['repair_report_einkaufen1'] = $request['repair_report_einkaufen1'];

Mail::send('emails.einkaufen', $data , function ($m) use ($delivery)
```

Not tested, but should give you desired result.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What doesn't work, what's the error?

Comment: ErrorException in cdb03cbd00269fc1780a38d5bc24b1cd61a79fad.php line 2:
Undefined variable: data (View: D:\Documents\Martin\projects\syworkx\resources\views\emails\einkaufen.blade.php)

Comment: Can you please paste your controller and view code, I can't tell anything from only one line of code your provided.

Comment: I would like to send by email only data what I put in the textarea. I have 5 fields for inks and 5 for decribe. Sometimes I used only 2 links, sometimes I use 5 link. How can I send only fields with data?

The mail is sent now.